# Auto configure Nginx server from Node JS app?

Tags: node.js, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

Say there is a Node js application running on localhost:3000, is there a way to configure a new location(path) in Nginx server from the app so that I do not have to rewrite location block of Nginx everytime new app is up?
Any way to write **function setupNginx(hostname,port,nginxPath)** like this?

Comment: actually you dont have to. you can proxy pass your domain to localhost:3000 with generic path such as / and this would be enough to open all your node paths to be public

Comment: Paths will open only for that application, what if there is a new app all together, say running on port 5000, how to connect to it without manually rewriting location block of the server?

Comment: then you should write a script that updates nginx sites-available which is a dangerous action since any bug causes all your paths fail